# TAB completion acting weird

Tags: bash

I'm using RPi on Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy) with bash, and have a problem with tab completion.

By default, it only shows the first match, even if there are more. If I press TAB more, nothing happens, there are four as you can see:
[image]

When I edit /etc/inputrc and add this to the end:
`"\C-i": menu-complete`

I get this weird result, first tab shows first match, second tab adds another one, and starts to cycle through.

[image]

I want first tab to show first match, and then concurrent tabs to cycle through. Any ideas? :)

Comment: It seems to have worked when i edited .inputrc (which didn't exist) and added `TAB: menu-complete`. What is the difference between /etc/inputrc and .inputrc?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wierd!

You are trying to execute a *python* command which is only valid for *python files* (*.py & *.pyc). There may be others, but I don't know that much.

If you try *nano* (or *ls*, as you did), then TAB, it will auto-complete all four!

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/inputrc` provide settings on global environment, `~/.inputrc` contains users settings, i.e.: if you create a new user, you find the same issue you have now fixed until create new `~/.inputrc` on this new user's `home`

Comment: So the format in these two files differ? That really doesn't explain the (from what I find) strange behaviour, and why it works while inside .inputrc?

Comment: They are the "same" kind of file, simply `/etc/inputrc` provide settings on a global level, `~/.inputrc` on local user level, if there is no `~/.inputrc` the global one is the default settings, also if there is the same settings on both files, the local one win, so you are a user, settings up your own local settings, it works in `~/.inputrc` and it is all fine, try to add `TAB: menu-complete` on your `/etc/inputrc` and delete `~/.inputrc`